# dart2js compiled Polymer Dart application is not running in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

I am unable to get a dart2js compiled polymer dart project to even load in IE 11.  I am a bit confused since it runs in Chrome and Firefox perfectly fine.  Here are my steps:

- Used stagehand to create a new web-polymer application.
- Without changing any dependencies, I ran pub get.
- Ran the application in Dartium using Webstorm's Open in Browser -> Dartium and verified the string reversing sample loaded.
- Ran pub build to compile my project into JavaScript.
- Navigated to my build\web directory, and started up a simple HTTP server (python -m SimpleHTTPServer or node's http-server)
- Opened the IP address and port listed in Chrome and Firefox, application worked as expected
- Opened the IP address and port listed in IE 11 and got a blank page.

I did open up the developer tools in IE 11 and noticed an error being thrown from my index.bootstrap.initialize.dart.js file with the text "Unsupported operation: extendsTag does not match base native class"

Again I did not change anything, I was just curious to see the compiled application run.  Is there something I am missing or forgot to do to get this to run in IE 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you run into this issue  https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/682

> It looks like this **does** work if you use the full polyfill (webcomponents.js not webcomponents-lite.js).
>
> Looks like this is caused by the template element not existing on IE. The full polyfill adds it which is why that works, where the lite version doesn't do a full polyfill.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm still coming up to speed with all the bits in play with this stuff so I need to make sure I'm searching github issues as well for these types of things.